# I am trying to access the camera

Tags: java, android

I am new to android studio. I want to display camera on a screen and click pictures directly. When I run my code, I get error in the manifest. 
When I put mouse over "Android.hardware.Camera" it shows "android.hardware.Camera is deprecated".
I have edited the AndroidManifest.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.none.www.dumpcam"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="25"
        android:targetSdkVersion="26" />

    <user-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.Camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:testOnly="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name="com.none.www.dumpcam.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.VERSION"
            android:value="26.1.0" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.arch.lifecycle.VERSION"
            android:value="27.0.0-SNAPSHOT" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.android.tools.ir.server.InstantRunContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.none.www.dumpcam.com.android.tools.ir.server.InstantRunContentProvider"
            android:multiprocess="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Yet I keep getting the following error. (also in the android.hardware.Camera Camera is checked )

```
Error:(11) error: unknown element <user-feature> found.
Error:(11) unknown element <user-feature> found.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
```

I am using android studio 3.0.1. 
Edit:
In the above code, the error is in the `<user-feature>` tag. However, when I am editing, I am using  as suggested in the comments which does not get highlighted as displays fine(without those red underlines). When I run the code, the  automattically changes to `<user-feature>` and shows the error stated above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is described in the log you provide.

```
<user-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.Camera"
        android:required="true" />
```

is wrong.

It should be:

```
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
```

---

**EDIT:**

In the AndroidManifest file at the bottom you have two options: Text and Merged Manifest check out you are at the Text option.

Comment: When I run uses-feature, it automatically changes the code to user-feature.

Comment: Just write it without using the "help" android studio provides. And change the name from Camera to camera. 
I use it like that.

Comment: @ArjunKashyap, it might be bug in the Studio. There is no such element as `<user-feature>` in manifest schema, so it should never show up as autocompleted value there.

Comment: I am doing just as you are asking. Once I complete my code and Run it, the code automatically gets changed. <uses-feature> becomes <user-feature>, camera becomes Camera(with a cross)

Comment: Change your AnfroidManifest NOT the merged one.

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska what do you mean not the merged ones? I can see only one AndroidManifest.xml in the manifests folder.

Comment: In the AndroidManifest file at the bottom you have two options: `Text` and `Merged Manifest` check out you are at the Text option.

Comment: The merged manifest is a build intermediate, and contains stuff from your manifest and from all of the manifests from your dependencies. If you want to do any changes you need to modify your real AndroidManifest.xml in your app/src

Comment: Did it solve your case? Or still happening this problem?